# Как установить фиксированный размер текстового поля в Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

В частности интересует виджет Text. В нижеследующем примере виджет Text, при задании слишком большого размера шрифта, виджет растягивается. Как задать ему фиксированный размер, независимо от размера шрифта?

```
import Tkinter
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText

class DialogMessages():

    def __init__(self):
        self.text = "Your text!" * 100 # текст окна
        self.size_font = "12"          # размер шрифта окна

        self.root = Tkinter.Tk()

        self.width_screen = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.height_screen = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        self.body = Tkinter.Canvas(self.root, width=437, height=250)
        self.body.pack()

        self.rectangle_text = Tkinter.Frame(self.body)
        self.rectangle_text.pack()

        self.body_text = ScrolledText(self.rectangle_text, width=1, height=1)
        self.body_text.pack()

        self.root.geometry("%sx%s+%s+%s" % (437, 267, int(self.width_screen * 0.35),
                                             int(self.height_screen * 0.35)
                                             ))

    def show(self):
        self.body_text.insert("1.0", self.text)
        self.body_text.config(font=("family", self.size_font), state="disabled")

        self.root.mainloop()

window = DialogMessages()
# Варьируя данную переменную, можно видеть,
# как текстовое поле уменьшается либо увеличивается.
window.size_font = "5"
window.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение следующее: задавать размер не для текстового поля (для него размер задается в символах), а для фрейма, в котором текстовое поле лежит, и отключить для этого фрейма изменение размера при изменение размеров вложенных элементов управления с помощью методов `pack_propagate()` или `grid_propagate()`.

В случае, описанном в вопросе, это будет выглядеть так:

```
self.rectangle_text = Tkinter.Frame(self.body, width=100, height=100)
self.rectangle_text.pack()
self.rectangle_text.pack_propagate(False)

self.body_text = ScrolledText(self.rectangle_text)
self.body_text.pack()
```

Если элементы управления внутри фрейма размещаются с помощью `grid`, то изменение размера фрейма нужно отключать при помощи `self.rectangle_text.grid_propagate(False)`.