# Как установить размер блока с текстом в пикселях

Tags: python, tkinter

очень нужно, что бы размер блока с текстом был именно в пикселях, а не в буквах. Функция `place()` в моём коде не подходит (либо я просто не знаю как сделать так, что бы всё работало корректно)

Итак, задумка такая - даём программе длину и ширину прямоугольника, программа считывает текущий размер окна и вычисляет сторону квадрата, из которых состоит весь прямоугольник, таким образом, что бы можно было составить прямоугольник из этих квадратов, и что бы он был на весь экран. Скорее всего вы ничего не поняли, что я сейчас сказал, но сейчас объясню на примере.

Допустим: входные данные **8**, **5** (то есть нужный нам прямоугольник шириной 8 и высотой 5 квадратов). Ширина окна: **1180x720**. Мы делим 1180 // 8 = **147**, потом делим 720 // 5 = **144**. полученные цифры почти совпадают, но меньшее из них - **144**. И ведь действительно, прямоугольник получится шириной 144 * 8 = **1152** и высотой 144 * 5 = **720** пикселей, и прямоугольник по максимуму занимает всё пространство. Осталось только разместить квадраты со стороной 144 пикселя.

К слову, почти весь код я уже написал:

```
import tkinter as tk

def side():
    global main_frame
    x, y = 8, 5
    side_square = min(int(window.geometry().split("+")[0].split("x")[0]) // x, int(window.geometry().split("+")[0].split("x")[1]) // y)
    print(side_square)
    main_frame.destroy()
    main_frame = tk.Frame()
    main_frame.grid()
    for number_line in range(y):
        for number_square in range(x):
            space = tk.Label(main_frame, text="square", width=side_square, height=side_square, bg="green")
            space.grid(column = number_square, row = number_line)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1180x720")
main_frame = tk.Frame()
main_frame.grid()
btn = tk.Button(main_frame, text="Узнать длину стороны квадрата", command=side)
btn.grid()
window.mainloop()
```

Если нажать кнопку, то в консоли выдастся сторона квадрата в пикселях, а вот при расстановке этих квадратов, они получаются вытянутыми вниз и огромными. Разумеется я понимаю, что ширина и высота блока с тестом указывается в буквах, но очень хотелось бы сделать из них пиксели. Что нибудь на подобие `width=pixels(side_square)`.

Comment: Положить текстовое поле в фрейм с полным "прилеганием", для фрейма задать размер в пикселях.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как установить фиксированный размер текстового поля в Tkinter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/385129/1365)

Comment: @insolor, если я не ошибаюсь, то в таком случае лишняя часть тестового поля просто обрезается, а ведь в обрезанном месте может находиться текст. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Нет, края текстового поля прилегает к краям фрейма, само поле не обрезается. Если текст выходит за границы текстового поля - он в любом случае будет обрезаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рабочий пример:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1180x720")

text_frame = tk.Frame(window, width=1100, height=700)
text_frame.pack()
# Запрещаем вложенным во фрейм виджетам менять размер фрейма под себя
# (уменьшать или увеличивать):
text_frame.pack_propagate(False)

text = tk.Text(text_frame)
# Текстовое поле будет расширяться до размера фрейма, в котором оно лежит:
text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')  

window.mainloop()
```