# Tkinter как Entry убольшит в толщину высоту ширину и тд

Tags: python, tkinter, entry

Tkinter как Entry убольшит в толщину высоту ширину и тд ошибка. У меня в том что я пишу ширину width а потом высоту *длину команда height в чем ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не помешало бы уточнение, что вы подразумеваете под толщиной? Толщину границ или что?

Answer (score 1):

В `Tkinter` у `Entry` нет параметра `height`. Если Вы хотите большое поле, можете посмотреть в сторону виджета [`Text`](https://metanit.com/python/tkinter/3.1.php).

Answer (score 1):

По аналогии с этим ответом: [Как установить фиксированный размер текстового поля в Tkinter?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584475/1365)

Создать фрейм с нужным размером, запретить ему сужаться под размер содержимого. Потом в этом фрейме разместить текстовое поле с расширением под размер фрейма.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

frame = tk.Frame(width=100, height=100)
frame.pack()
frame.pack_propagate(False)

entry = tk.Entry(frame)
entry.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]